# In gimp how can I get the edges of a filled rectangle selection to look like a painted area?

Tags: gimp

How can I get a paint colorblock effect on the edges similar to what is on the edges of the red portion of Saul Bass's One Two Three poster?

I have two layers, one is a background that is white. The second layer (above the background layer) has a rectangle selection that is filled with color. I would like the edges of color filled square to resemble the red edges here:

[image: poster]
<sub>(source: [wellmedicated.com](https://wellmedicated.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/one_two_three.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

#### Jagged edges with Gimp

These are the steps I took for jagged edges using a predefined default Script Fu filter.

1. Select an area:

   [image]
2. Choose *Select - Distort...*:

   [image]
   Choose appropriate values for desired effect.

   [image]
3. Bucket fill selection:

   [image]
4. Add an artistic effect for brush strokes

   - *Grow selection* by the desired width of the effect
   - choose a *Filter -> Artistic* which meets your needs.

   [image]
   *(GimPressionist Crosshatch)*